# Some problem with touch events with cef and SDL2

Tags: c++, linux, mouseevent, sdl, chromium-embedded

I'm experiencing some problem to getting working touch events with CEF in offscreen rendering using SDL2 in some situation:

Im writing an SDL-CEF application that need to execute some online game into a videolottery. so I start the application from tty using startx and not in DE. Morever, I can't use the mouse but is only possible use touchscreen to interact with the machine.The touch event work pretty well in the most os cases, but with some game the click event is not recognized by the web application.

For pass the correct event to the CEF browser I have written some specialized handler functions that catchs the SDL_Event and converts their to CEF_Event. Fo example for processing tauch events I have a function called `handleFingerEvent(SDL_Event, CEF_Browser*)`. This specialized function is called from a generic `handleEvents(SDL_Event, VEF_Browser*)` handler function of highter level .

```cpp
// The Touch Event Hendler function
void handleFingerEvent(SDL_Event &e, CefBrowser* browser) {
    CefMouseEvent event;

    switch (e.type) {
    case SDL_FINGERDOWN:
        // W_SIZE and H_SIZE are the dimension of the screen in px
        if (e.tfinger.pressure > 0.9) {
            event.x = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.x*W_SIZE);
            event.y = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.y*H_SIZE);

            browser->GetHost()->SendMouseClickEvent(event, 
                                                    MBT_LEFT,
                                                    false, 1);
        }
        break;

    case SDL_FINGERUP:
        event.x = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.x*W_SIZE);
        event.y = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.y*H_SIZE);

        browser->GetHost()->SendMouseClickEvent(event, MBT_LEFT, true, 1);
        break;

    case SDL_FINGERMOTION: {
        int scrollX = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.dx);
        int scrollY = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.dy);

        event.x = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.x*W_SIZE);
        event.y = static_cast<int>(e.tfinger.y*H_SIZE);

        browser->GetHost()->SendMouseWheelEvent(event, scrollX, scrollY);
        break;
        }

        default:
            break;
        }
}
```

```cpp
void handleEvents(SDL_Event &e, CefBrowser *browser) {

    switch (e.type) {
        // Key events
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            handleKeyEvent(e, browser);
            break;

        // Window events
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
            handleWindowEvent(e, browser);
            break;

    //Mouse events
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            case SDL_MOUSEWHEEL:
            handleMouseEvent(e, browser);
            break;

        // Touch events
        case SDL_FINGERDOWN:
        case SDL_FINGERMOTION:
        case SDL_FINGERUP:
            handleFingerEvent(e, browser);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I call it from a SDL_PollEvent() while loop like this:

```
browser = CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowserSync(window_info, 
                                            browserClient, //My BrowserClient implementation 
                                            "https://www.something.sometother", 
                                            browserSettings, // The cef setting 
                                            nullptr, nullptr);


while(!browserClient->closeAllowed()) {

        //Send events to the browser
        SDL_Event e;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0){
            //Quit and window resize
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                browser->GetHost()->CloseBrowser(false);
            }
            else if (e.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && e.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
                renderHandler->resize(e.window.data1, e.window.data2);
                browser->GetHost()->WasResized();
            }
            else {
                handleEvents(e, browser.get());
            }
        }

        // Cef main work loop
        cefApp->doCefWork();

        //Set background color
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

        //Clear window/renderer
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        renderHandler->render();

        //Update screen contents
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
```

Now I really don't know why in some game the event isn't caught by the browser. Morever if I open the game in a machine with mouse connected and a DM, and so I use the mouse pointer for interact with the game, it works without any problem. Maybe is there a better approach to send a click event to CefBrowser?

Comment: Try executing SendMouseMoveEvent before SendMouseClickEvent.

Comment: mmm, I don't know if this should be help. The cefSendMouseClickEvent() alredy knows the coordinates where need to send the click event, because that are passed through the CefEven x and y properties